# MariaDB foreign key auto generated index not created for the first column of PK

Tags: indexing, mariadb, foreign-keys, innodb

i'm facing a question without answer. I can't understand why the auto generated index from the FK creation is not working when the column seems to be the first one of PK, what i mean :

Create a simple schema with :

```sql
CREATE TABLE cat (name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE dog (name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE cat_dog_couple
(
    cat_name VARCHAR(255),
    dog_name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (cat_name, dog_name),
    CONSTRAINT fk__cat_dog_couple__cat_name FOREIGN KEY (cat_name) references cat(name),
    CONSTRAINT fk__cat_dog_couple__dog_name FOREIGN KEY (dog_name) references dog(name)
);
```

These indexes will be generated :

```
+----------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
|     Table      | Non_unique |           Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
| cat_dog_couple |         0  | PRIMARY                      |            1 | cat_name    |
| cat_dog_couple |         0  | PRIMARY                      |            2 | dog_name    |
| cat_dog_couple |         1  | fk__cat_dog_couple__dog_name |            1 | dog_name    |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

[Screen show index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwFiP.png)

I don't really understand why the index **fk__cat_dog_couple__cat_name** is not created?
Is it a bug ? A technical limitation ? A technical choice ?

Tested on MariaDB 10.4.x and 10.5.x.

Comment: *why the index fk__cat_dog_couple__cat_name is not created?* Because primary key prefix can be used. Swap columns in PK - and fk__cat_dog_couple__cat_name will be created whereas fk__cat_dog_couple__dog_name will not. Create unique/regular index with swapped columns in addition to PK - and none additional index will be created.

Comment: What do you mean by "Because primary key prefix can be used" ?    
"Swap columns in PK " I know it, i already tried it :P.   
"Create unique/regular index with swapped columns in addition to PK" That clearly what i want to avoid, and i want to understand why i have to do this only for the first column of PK ?

Comment: *What do you mean by "Because primary key prefix can be used" ?* Your PK expression is `(cat_name, dog_name)`. It can be used as common index by `(cat_name)` for FK reference checking (the rows in the index are sorted by `cat_name`). `cat_name` is a prefix of `cat_name, dog_name` expression. *why i have to do this only for the first column of PK ?* Because the index prefix can be used instead of separate index whereas middle part or postfix of the expression cannot. The rows in the index by `(cat_name, dog_name)` are sorted by `cat_name` but are not by `dog_name`.

Comment: So, is it true to say that - A composite PK will create a composite index - The composite index will work to index tuple `(cat_name, dog_name)` also `cat_name` (related to generated prefix) - To index `dog_name` a new index needs to be created ?

Comment: *is it true to say that - A composite PK will create a composite index* For InnoDB - this is not correct.

Comment: You create FK by `column` - server needs in the index where `column` is an expression or expression prefix. When you create FK by `(cat_name)` such index exists, it is PK. When you create FK by `(dog_name)` such index not exists, and server creates it.

Comment: I agree that the FK should have created an index on `dog_name`, not `cat_name`.  MySQL 8.0.28 worked correctly; file a bug report with MariaDB.  Meanwhile, manually add `INDEX(dog_name)`.

Comment: I checked using [latest development containers](https://mariadb.org/new-service-quay-io-mariadb-foundation-mariadb-devel/) of 10.2 -> 10.6 and all versions create the FK index on `dog_name` and not `cat_name`. Its also correct in `10.5.15`. I'm not sure which version you are currently using. [10.4.22](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e22d7e69f3c3264e3f5becc483a64dcd) also tested correctly.

Comment: And your screenshot shows `dog_name` too :-)

Comment: @danblack & Rick James yup it's just an error made by myself while copying the array (screenshot saves me) i just edited it.

Comment: @Akina _A composite PK will create a composite index For InnoDB - this is not correct._ What i was wonder is do create PK(col1, col2) will create INDEX(col1, col2)? After that with the documentation 8.3.5 Multiple-Column Indexes, i can easily understand what you explained to me.

Comment: To complete my comment above :  _If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3)._ (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: In InnoDB the primary key is clustered index. I.e. it does not create an index as separate on-disk structure.

Comment: MySQL<>MariaDB [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help] See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. PS Read the manual re all functionality/syntax you are using.

Comment: Fine, that's what I thought but I didn't express it well, i get it right now thank you so much for your time and explanations.